Are DInSAR and InSAR same?
I am reading papers that talk about InSAR methods. For subsidence, some papers have employed DInSAR approach and others InSAR. While the methods section explanation are similar, I would like an expert opinion if both the techniques are same or if DInSAR is one among the InSAR techniques (like POLSAR).

InSAR is the use of combining 2 SAR images taken during different moments in time, used for making digital elevation models.
DInSAR is the use of many SAR images taken during different moments in time.
Technically speaking, DInSAR is used for settlement detection. However, InSAR is commonly used as a synonym of DInSAR. When I worked for a company producing InSAR products, we never used the term DInSAR, but always used the data for settlement analysis with 20+ images.

Thank you. So if i use multiple 2-SAR images to look for subsidence/ ground movement, it'll be DInSAR?

yes, multiple SAR images is DInSAR
